# Real world examples of iOS UIKit Dynamics?

Tags: ios, iphone, dynamic-ui

iOS 7.0 has introduced a new feature called UIKit Dynamics. It allows the developer to define different forces and constraints (gravity, collision, attachments, arbitrary forces, spring, etc.) between UI elements (buttons, labels, table cells, etc.) and it contains a physics engine that animates these elements based on the forces and constraints. For example Game Center bubbles are implemented with the help of UIKit Dynamics.

Do you know any design guidelines, patterns or examples on how to design a cool dynamic UI with UIKit Dynamics?

Comment: Try searching YouTube for examples - there are some, like this one for example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YLn2WXDvv2E

Comment: Referring to "put on hold as off-topic" - this question is absolutely not about how to *implement* this feature - I'd like to see some real-world examples of UX utilizing dynamic elements that simulate real-world physics in their movement and relationship.

Comment: Reformatted the question to be about inspiration and ideas surrounding animations with UIKit Dynamics, rather than the actual implementation of it. With that said, I think a good site for inspiration regarding iOS animations would be [Capptivate.co](http://capptivate.co)

Comment: Thank you @VAlexander capptivate.co is really a cool source of inspirations, I wanted to see exactly this type of examples!